# displaying my selected radio button in textbox from another form

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer

How do I display the selected item from my `form2` groupbox radiobutton (3 radiobuttons and i can only display one) inside my `Form1` texbox.

This is my problem as I only know the code to display 1. if statments didn't work.

**Form1:**

```
public void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    Form2 fr2 = new Form2();
    textBox1.Text = fr2.receivet(textBox1.Text, fr2.radioButton1);
    
}
```

**Form2:**

```
internal string receivet(string textBox1, RadioButton radio)
{
    return textBox1 = radio.Text;
}
```

Comment: Any reason for tags c# 3 and 4 ?

Comment: tags removed. i just need advise or help to solve this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to create method like receivet, you can directly get RadioButton from Form object

```
public void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    Form2 fr2 = new Form2();
    string radioTxt = ""
    if (fr2.RadioButton1.Checked) 
    {
         radioTxt = fr2.RadioButton1.Text
    }
    else if (fr2.RadioButton2.Checked) 
    {
         radioTxt = fr2.RadioButton2.Text
    }
    else if (fr2.RadioButton3.Checked) 
    {
         radioTxt = fr2.RadioButton3.Text
    }

    textBox1.Text = radioTxt;

}
```

Comment: Yes I get you. But I just don't want to access 1 radio button at a time. I want when i run this application, Any radiobutton i check will be displayed in my textbox. This code only works for button 1 or any button i assign it to. I want to be able to access all. so that if i choose a radio button, it will be displayed. I have 4 radio buttons but i can only access 1 at a time. that is my problem

Comment: Appreciate you!!

Comment: If this solve your issue please mark it as answer

Answer (score 0):

In your code you create a new Form2 instance and take its value. You need to call the shown Form2 instance's function (and set it to public modifier).

Comment: internal is good enough if form1 and form2 are in the same assembly

Comment: Please add code sample also for more clearlity